# how do I get a result from neuroph studio to a java swing application

Tags: java, swing, neural-network

I have recently started getting my hands dirty on neuroph studio (trying their neural network systems), however I have to generate the output of the neural network system on a text box in a Java swing application. How can I do that? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

A text box is designed for a single line of text like name. For multiple lines, it is recommended to use a text area.
What is the output generated by neuroph studio which you wish to display? I peeked at their site and it seems the output is graphical

Comment: Thank you for responding Maneesh. The output generated out of neuroph studio is a double value (probability of an outcome). Is there a way to get that output on Java swing, since Neuroph is a Java framework only?

Comment: That would depend on the neuroph API. Does it expose any getter method for this value?
Once you have it, displaying it in the JTextField is as simple as calling JTextField#setText(String text)